# Suggestion for outdoor receptacle

Tags: electrical, lighting, receptacle, pool

I need to run a pool pump outdoors with an all weather extension cord. I also have string lights and lamps and other outdoor items I can plug into outdoor type receptacle with enclosures that hinge at each outlet. These are likely not designed to safely use them while its raining or continuously.

How can one cover the receptacles in a manner that allows things such as (all weather) lights and motors to be plugged in while the cover stays closed?  I'm in Charleston, SC btw.

Comment: Where on this planet are you?

Comment: Charleston, SC. No ice issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device you're after is called a *while in use* cover, or "bubble cover" more informally.  Get an *extra duty* one -- they're sturdier than the regular, cheapo flavor.

[image: while in use cover representative pic]

Answer (score 1):

Many products are advertised and UL listed for use outdoors.   In my experience this listing is only good for the 90 day warranty period!  Those "weather" covers always leak IME, are hard to open and often the latches break, and don't fit some cords very well.  Bad news all around.   Their real purpose seems to be to make the inspector go away.

I am much happier building a little "birdhouse" on top of the receptacle post, with a little door for access, and an open bottom for cords to exit.   That does not relieve you of the requirement to use a listed cover, but at least now the cover is 99% out of the rain and is likely to last a lot longer.

Comment: Thanks for info guys and gals, ordered one on amazon for about 10 bucks. Replaces the faceplate.

Comment: I think part of the problem with the while-in-use covers leaking is pressure differentials across the cover seal.  Sounds like something worth testing if you ask me...

Comment: I'll test it at the end of oct. to see how it's holding up.